# Number Greater Than With Float Point

Tags: regex

I am fairly new to regular expressions and I am having a time getting one that I have formulated to work correctly. Below is the expression that I have formulated.

```
^((?!^1[0-6]*\.?[0-2][0-4]+)^(\d+))$
```

I am trying to build an expression that will verify a number greater than 16.24. The input needs to be able to accept whole numbers like 17 without a user having to put in 17.00 to verify. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't a good use of regular expressions.  Just convert from string to an appropriate numeric datatype, and then perform a numeric comparison.

Comment: @thebradnet Are the numbers hidden within a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to use a regular expression to extract the numeric values then parse them to a number and compare them with the desired constant.

Javascript: Code Example

Numbers as strings:

```
var test = function(str){
    return 16.24 < parseFloat(str);
};
console.log( test("234.23") == true ); // true
console.log( test("-234.23") == false ); // true
```

Numbers hidden within strings with other characters.

```
var test = function (str) {
    var re,
    num;

    if (/[eE]/.test(str)) {
        // search for scientific numbers
        re = /-?\d+(\.\d+)?[eE]\d+/;
    } else {
        // search for whole or decimal numbers
        re = /-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/;
    }
    num = str.match(re);
    return 16.24 < parseFloat(num);
};
console.log(test("input = 234.23") == true); // true
console.log(test("input = 2e34") == true); // true
console.log(test("input = -2e34") == false); // true
console.log(test("input = -234.23") == false); // true
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked. I have been so caught up in doing this as a regular expression that I kind of forgot about doing it another way.